# iOS: How to see pictures on a network hard disk?

Tags: ios, photos, network

Which is the best free app for browsing and displaying pictures that are stored on a network hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are many, like for example [File Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8). But you would have found them with a easy google search too.

Add "free" to your search term and you find [My Computer Data](http://itunes.apple.com/app/my-computer-data/id399548310?mt=8). I haven't used, it's just the first search result.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the word free :-)

Comment: Also, does file browser allow me to "slideshow" the pictures like the original iPhone Photos app, or do I have to open each picture separately? Thanks!

Comment: Thank @Christian. Unfortunately My Computer Data works only for pcs and requires a server running on the pc. Btw I know that google gives me answer, however here I hope to find also some users' feedbacks.

Comment: @lucaghera Then rephrase your question to "which is the best free app" or something like this ;)